# Enter button works as tab

Tags: html, button, enter

I just have button in a page and nothing else

```
<button>hello</button>
```

When I open the page and press tab it comes to button but instead I want it in such a way that if I hit enter it should come to that button.

This is the code that I have written but it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.EntTab').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) e.keyCode = 9;
    return false;
});
});
```

Need help in tackling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this!

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $("button#hel").focus();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 9) {
      var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", {
        keyCode: 9
      });
      $(document).trigger(e);
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hel">hello</button>
<button>hello</button>
<button>hello</button>
```

Comment: No it is not coming to hello button. Even tab is not working now. Is it working for u ?

Comment: what if I have two buttons and I want this action only for the first one ?

Comment: Add an `id` or `class` to the button. Else use `$("button:nth-child(1)").focus();`, this selects the first button.

Comment: If using an id `$("button#hel").focus();`, if it's an class use `$("button.hel").focus();`

Comment: Its working but my tab is not working for the next button !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108166/discussion-between-pugazh-and-reaching-out).

Comment: I created another function which reads tab and called the second button by Id. It's working now. :-)