# Enter key for button

Tags: javascript, html, button, enter

I have changed my code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398003/enter-button-works-as-tab) discussion in such a way that if I press enter it comes to first button and if I press tab it goes to second button. But now my problem is, from the first button if I press enter it is not invoking that button and if I press tab from the second button again it is not going to first button.
So I need these things to happen:

1) From first/second button if I hit enter, the button should invoke(click)

2) If I hit tab from second button it should go between first and second.

This is the code that I have used.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hel">hello</button>
<button id="hel1" >hello1</button>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $("button#hel").focus();
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                $("button#hel1").focus();
            }
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

What change should I make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexis is close, but you want the focus to go to the button after the first enter, so what you want to do is set a detector. You also want it to cycle through the buttons when you press tab, going back to the top if they are on the last when they prss tab. If a button is focused, click it, if not, got to the first button.

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var currentBtn = $(".mybtn:focus"),
  inputs = $(".mybtn"),
  currentIndex = inputs.index(currentBtn),
  next = inputs.filter(function (index) {
   if (currentIndex < inputs.length) {
    return index == currentIndex + 1;
   } else {
    return index == 0;
   }
  });

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   if (currentBtn.length) {
    currentBtn.click();
   } else {
    $(".mybtn").first().focus();
   }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 9) {
   if (currentBtn.length) {
   if (currentBtn.is(".mybtn:last")) {
     $(".mybtn").first().focus();
  } else {
     next.focus();
    }
   } else {
    $(".mybtn").first().focus();
   }
  }
  return false;
 });
});

$("button#hel").on('click', function(){
 alert("hello press");
});

$("button#hel1").on('click', function(){
 alert("hello1 press");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hel" class='mybtn'>hello</button>
<button id="hel1" class='mybtn' >hello1</button>
```

Comment: But the alert message is calling twice

Comment: sorted the alert pop up which comes twice. But followed your approach though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

It works but there's maybe a better way to do that.

```js
$(function() {
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $(".mybtn").is(":focus").trigger("click");
}
if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    if($("button#hel").is(":focus"))
    $("button#hel1").focus();
  else
    $("button#hel").focus();
}
return false;
});

$("button#hel").focus();
});

$("button#hel").click(function(){
  alert("hello press");
  });

$("button#hel1").click(function(){
  alert("hello1 press");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hel" class='mybtn'>hello</button>
<button id="hel1" class='mybtn' >hello1</button>
```

Comment: If i press enter when i opened the page it is not coming to button1

Comment: It's normal the button is not focus. You can change this easily with a test in enter event. I've edit my answer

Comment: I don't want the button to invoke first on pressing enter, i want that to happen only on the second time when I'm pressing enter. When I'm pressing enter for the first time it should come to the first button. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand... You want each time you press enter it change of button ?

Comment: No just the first time to get to the button and that's it. After that only tab to change buttons and enter to invoke buttons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108199/discussion-between-reaching-out-and-alexis).